# Write SQL query to return only the latest record that is modified with CTE and inner join

Tags: sql, common-table-expression

I believe I'm incorrect in my [CTE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_and_recursive_queries_in_SQL#Common_table_expression) query.

```
WITH LastModified AS (
SELECT
    Id, MAX(ModifiedON) as Last_Modified
FROM
    EventTransaction
GROUP BY
    ProductNumber)
SELECT
   ProductNumber, ProductDescription, CreatedON, CreatedByUser as UserCreated, ModifiedON, ModifiedByUser as UserModified
FROM
    EventTransaction
    INNER JOIN UserAccount on
    EventTransaction.ModifiedByUser=UserAccount.UserAccountId
order by ProductNumber
```

I keep getting error message 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 48.
Column 'EventTransaction.Id' is invalid in the select list, because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I am expecting to have one row for each product number with the selected information. The select statement and inner join are working.

Comment: as you don't need rhe id field delete it and why have you a CTE if you don't use it

Comment: A [mcve] would make this much clearer,

Answer (score 0):

You selected "id" column and max() but at the end of the code, used group by "ProductNumber", it's wrong, you should aggregate based on your selected columns, Group By "id" is the correct statement.

if you want to use "WITH AS" structure, you should create something like this:

```
WITH
TABLE1 AS (SELECT * FROM SOURCE)
, TABLE2 AS (SELECT * FROM SOURCE)
, TABLE3 AS (SELECT * FROM SOURCE)

SELECT
    a.*
    ,b.*
    ,c.*
FROM TABLE1 a 
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 b ON a.key = b.key
LEFT JOIN TABLE3 c ON a.key = c.key
```

So here's a corrected version of your query:

```
WITH LastModified AS (
    SELECT 
        ProductNumber, MAX(ModifiedON) as Last_Modified
    FROM 
        EventTransaction
    GROUP BY 
        ProductNumber
)

SELECT 
    ET.ProductNumber, 
    ET.ProductDescription, 
    ET.CreatedON, 
    ET.CreatedByUser as UserCreated, 
    ET.ModifiedON, 
    ET.ModifiedByUser as UserModified
FROM 
    EventTransaction ET
INNER JOIN 
    UserAccount UA on ET.ModifiedByUser = UA.UserAccountId
INNER JOIN 
    LastModified LM on ET.ProductNumber = LM.ProductNumber and ET.ModifiedON = LM.Last_Modified
ORDER BY 
    ET.ProductNumber;
```